# Telegram bot message read callback

Tags: webhooks, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Is it possible to get callbacks in the webhook whenever a user reads the message sent by the bot, using Telegram bot API?

It is not documented, and I cannot figure out a way how to achieve it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Telegram actually provides two [APIs](https://core.telegram.org/api):

- The [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/api#bot-api) allows you to easily create programs that use Telegram messages for an interface.
- The [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api) allows you to build your own customized Telegram clients.

The feature you are looking for is not available via the Bot API, rather it's only available via Telegram API.

Also

1 check = message delivered to the Telegram cloud (and is waiting for your chat partner to see it in Telegram), notification sent (if the recipient is accepting notifications).

2 checks = message read (recipient opened Telegram and the conversation with your message).

> We don't have an additional status for 'message delivered to device',
>   because you can use Telegram on multiple devices simultaneously. Since
>   you don't know which one of their devices the person is actually
>   using, delivery to one of the devices becomes irrelevant.
>   [Telegram Support]

Comment: Can I send messages to users via Telegram API?

Comment: Yes, as a Telegram user not as a Bot.

Comment: @ManzoorWani But you can send messages to Bot-users ALSO as a Bot.

Comment: @GiorgioRobino yes that's true, because the two use different APIs

Answer (score 7):

As other  answered, the feature you are looking for is not available via the Bot API.

That's, for me, conceptually, a BUG, or at least a Change request (CR).

Using Telegram API instead of Bot API is a workaround. :(

We need to ask Telegram the CR, implicitly pointed out on the original question by @user7518s.

> BTW: it could be great to have a callback for voice/media
>   messages. In case of a long audio (or video) message, for example, it could be useful to
>   know if the message is completely listened (or watched) with timestamp of
>   interruption in case of a message partially listened (watched)!

Answer (score 5):

At the moment this feature is not available with Telegram Bot API.

> We don‘t have a ’delivered to device' status for messages because
>   Telegram can run on as many devices as you want. So which particular
>   one would that check mean?

**FAQ:** https://telegram.org/faq#q-what-do-the-green-checks-mean

---

**EDIT**

You can achieve the read status of messages using the regular Telegram API (https://core.telegram.org/methods)

---

[Related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830013/how-can-a-telegram-bot-figure-out-that-user-has-opened-the-chat-window)

Comment: Ok, but they do have green checks--one check and two checks--in the interface. How can I get them via API?

Comment: @bimbari you should be able to achieve that with the regular API.